# Mac OS X Folder Sync Tool

Tags: osx-lion

I want to synchronize a folder containing a lots of Word documents between my MacBook Air and my MacMini. Im running Lion on both machines. If a document has changed on both sides I would like to have the software offer me a merge dialog. The only software I found yet which looks like it can do is: DeltaWalker but I'm not sure if its more a Merge than a Sync Tool. Does anyone know a better solution? Preferably the tool should automatically mount the other machines drive/folder when I click sync.

I'm looking for a solution which works in my LAN. No cloud services like Dropbox please.

Comment: how about using git? http://blog.futureshock-ed.com/2009/08/using-git-to-synchronise-my-documents.html

Comment: Does it have a Merge option showing me the differences?

Answer (score 3):

Working with Git and a central repository on one machine would work.

You could use the excellent GUI client [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to get a really good overview for merging when conflicts occur.

Note however that Word documents will not be treated as plain text files by Git. A Word document is formatted text with quite an obscure markup and possibly embedded media. Therefore Git will either treat them as binary files or the diff will contain the obscure markup as well as your content.

Any software only operating on a byte-by-byte basis without actually understanding the file format will have the same problem when it comes to show a usable diff between versions.